# Delete the record by AutoNumber field with angular.js

Tags: angularjs

how to Delete the record  by AutoNumber field with angular.js ?

**Scenario:**

default page is :

[image]

When I'm push a record into $scope.users :

[image]

```
$scope.user={
   Name:stackoverflow,
   Family:stackoverflow.com,
   ID:undefined
}
```

Then record will be displayed :

[image]

When I want to delete the record, the following error occurs:

> he parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Void DeleteUser(Int32)'
>   in 'Angular_02.Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must
>   be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

**because ID field is undefined**

Delete user codes into the server :

```
[HttpPost]
public void DeleteUser(int id)
{
  var userService=new UserService();
  userService.Delete(id);
}
```

How do I fix this error?
I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet. Where I wrong? I really do not know what to do. I wrote all the details below. I've tried and did not succeed.

app.js file :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller("UserController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.users = "";
    $scope.user = "";

    // Get User Scope
    var getUsersRequest = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "/User/GetUsers",
    });

    getUsersRequest.success(
        function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        }
    );
    // End Get User Scope


    // Add User Scope

    $scope.addUser = function (user) {

        var addUserRequest = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/User/AddUser",
            data: user
        });

        addUserRequest.success(
            function () {
                $scope.users.push(user);
                $scope.user = "";
            }
        );
    };
    // End Add User Scope

    // Delete User Scope
    $scope.deleteUser = function (id, index) {
        var addUserRequest = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/User/DeleteUser",
            data: { "id": id }
        });

        addUserRequest.success(
            function () {
                $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
            }
        );
    };
    // End Delete User Scope
});
```

html code :

```
<div ng-controller="UserController" ng-app="myApp">
    <span>Count :  {{users.length}} User</span>
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <span>Name : {{user.Name}}</span>
        <span>Family : {{user.Family}}</span>
        <section style="float: left;" ng-click="deleteUser(user.ID,$index);">
            <a href="Javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
        </section>
    </div>

    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="addUser(user)">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.Name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.Family" placeholder="Family" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

my table scripte:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Family] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

update :

add user in service :

```
private UserContext _userContext;
        public void Add(User user)
        {
            using (_userContext = new UserContext())
            {
                _userContext.Users.Add(user);
                _userContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your action looks for adding new user but probably something like :

```
[HttpPost]
public User AddUser(User user)
{
  var userService=new UserService();
  userService.AddUser(user);
  userService.Comit();
// make sure that you return created user
return user
}
```

then in your js part

```
 $scope.addUser = function (user) {

         $http.post("/User/AddUser",user).then(function(response){
               $scope.users.push(response.data);
                $scope.user = {};

        });               

    };
// End Add User Scope
```

if that wouldn't work please post yours addUser action from server side.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the "add user" web service. The response from the add user web service should return your user as it exists in the database (or at the very least the user ID). By sending the client the new ID you now have enough information to delete the user.